# Creating a data rescue partition

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, dd, disk-image, file-recovery

I am trying to recover deleted files from a Windows HDD (320 Gb) with multiple partitions. Have three questions:

1. Will `dd if=/dev/sdb of=~/image_sdb.img bs=4096` create an image of all partitions together?
2. Will deleted files be included in the image?
3. Can I use a recovery program like `TestDisk` directly on that image or are there reasons to prefer the original disk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>I don't know the answer to Question 1.</strike>

Deleted files will be included in a `dd` copy, since it is a byte-for-byte copy from the disk (not file-by-file).

If your recovery program can work on disk images, it should work the same as if it was a physical drive, once again because the image should be byte-for-byte the same as the disk.

**EDIT**
It [appears](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disk_Cloning#Cloning_an_entire_hard_disk) that `dd` can be used to copy all partitions. The linked wiki page suggests using `dd` like this: `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=4096 conv=notrunc,noerror,sync`, so perhaps you should use `dd if=/dev/sdb of=~/image_sdb.img bs=4096 conv=notrunc,noerror,sync`.